# how to solve recursion of given algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

```
int gcd(n,m)
{
  if (n%m ==0) return m;
  n = n%m;
  return gcd(m,n);
}
```

I solved this and i got

```
T(n, m) = 1 + T(m, n%m)  if n > m
        = 1 + T(m, n)    if n < m
        = m              if n%m == 0
```

I am confused how to proceed further to get the final result. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What is T? Is it the number of comparisons or time taken or what?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: did you miss homework tag or we are in wrong way?

Comment: Are you trying to find the complexity?

Comment: @Mark ByersT is the time taken to solve this algorithm

Comment: @Wormbo I am trying to calculate the time complexity of Euclidean algorithm to calculate GCD

Comment: @MAziar Bouali I just improved my recursion part, as of my interest in it, its not a homework at all.

Comment: @algoh: I doubt there's a simple closed form solution. But what you have so far is also wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the size of the next values of m and n depend on exactly what the previous values were, not just their size. Knuth goes into this in detail in "The Art of Computer Programming" Vol 2: Seminumerical algorithms, section 4.5.3. After about five pages he proves what you might have guessed, which is that the worst case is when m and n are consecutive fibonacci numbers. From this (or otherwise!) it turns out that in the worst case the number of divisions required is linear in the logarithm of the larger of the two arguments.

After a great deal more heavy-duty math, Knuth proves that the average case is also linear in the logarithm of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

mcdowella has given a perfect answer to this.

For an intuitive explaination you can think of it this way,

if n >= m, n mod m < n/2;

This can  be shown as,

if m < n/2, then:
n mod m < m < n/2

if m > n/2, then: n mod m = n-m < n/2

So effectively you are halving the larger input, and in two calls both the arguments will be halved.